# As of Mountain Lion, Google Chrome has asked for permission to view my contacts. Does this mean that it has likely had unrestricted access before?

Tags: contacts, google-chrome, macos, privacy

I'm not sure why Chrome wants this access, but since prior to Mountain Lion there wasn't a prompt for this, it makes me think that it must have been looking at them this whole time. Right?

Comment: Interesting, when does it ask? Mine didn't ask for anything...

Comment: It was only the first time I launched it.

Comment: My version of Chrome doesn't ask either.  Whether or not it was the first time you launched it is irrelevant; apps need to ask for Contacts permission on ML regardless of if you've launched them before.

Comment: FYI, the reason why Chrome prompts to access your Address Book is for autofilling forms. There is a setting to include info from your address card. It probably will not prompt if you have not enabled this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, right.  Round about Tiger (10.4) Apple introduced a nice neat way for apps to integrate with your address book and calendar data stores etc.  At the time it was a novel thing that allowed for any number of clever calendar widgets etc, and stuff that could happily replace the in-built tools (or enhance them) without you having to change anything at an account or data level.

These days, because of a number of high profile mobile apps getting in trouble for doing what the desktop OS have been doing for years, they are cranking up the security and privacy options.

Answer (score 10):

To turn this off and eliminate the error messages, you can do the following:

1. Click the Chrome menu  on the browser toolbar. Select Settings.
2. Click Show advanced settings and find the "Passwords and forms" section.
3. Click "Manage Autofill Settings"
4. Deselect the "Include addresses from my Address Book card" checkbox.

Comment: +1 for pinpointing the precise feature that is the source of the behaviour!